# Conditional row-wise average

Tags: r

I have a simple question. I have a data.frame that looks like this:

df

> ```
>  A             B             C         Exclusion_criteria
>  3             4             5                 3      
>  2                                             1     
>  6             9                               2
> ```

I simply would like to mean rows of columns A, B and C (row-wise) when the Exclusion_criteria is different from 1 (e.g. for all cases except Exclusion_criteria == 1).

Can anyone help me please?

Kind regards

Comment: Are you familiar with `rowMeans`? Regarding filtering by condition - there hundreds of posts on SO. Finally, judging by those blanks, your columns aren't even numeric. I would suggest you will handle that part first (first find out if they are characters of factors - and then Google).

Answer (score 1):

We can loop over the rows with `apply`, remove the element that is showed in the 4th column by, and get the `mean`

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) mean(x[1:3][-x[4]], na.rm = TRUE))
#[1] 3.5 NaN 6.0
```

---

Or another option is to replace the values in 'df' based on the row/column index (from 4th column) to NA and do a `rowMeans`

```
df[cbind(1:nrow(df), df[,4])] <- NA
rowMeans(df[1:3], na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 3.5 NaN 6.0
```